# Is it "Breathing in breaststroke is easy." or "Breathing in the breaststroke is easy."?

Tags: definite-articles, sports

I'm never sure if I need the article or not in that particular case...

Comment: Be careful to not being misunderstood about *breathing in* equivalent to *inhaling*.

Comment: That's funny Josh as I'm the author of that article. So "Breathing in breaststroke" is correct? (English is a second language for me)

Comment: I find it to be confusing either way.  If I were intimately familiar with swimming, I *might* understand it, but to a mere layman like me, I think of "the breaststroke" as an "activity", and so to me the sentence would make more sense if it were:  "Breathing while doing the breaststroke is easy."

Comment: I like your suggestion Joe it sounds much better that way. I think I'll integrate it in the article. Thanks.

One day I'll need to seriously study English grammar.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that, yes, you need the article.

Long answer is that *breath in* is a verb that is synonymous with *inhale*.  Most English speakers would parse your sentence with a meaning of "inhaling one breaststroke", which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

A better sentence would be (from Joe):

> Breathing while doing the breaststroke is easy.